# Getting this error after installing node js, npm, aurelia-cli when building aurelia project repository using au build command on ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, aurelia

Getting this error after installing node js, npm, aurelia-cli when building aurelia project repository using au build command

```
nzafran@CN-176:/var/www/html/Magnfi-master$ au build
    Local aurelia-cli v1.3.1 Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
    INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 2.1.0 performance-now 
    INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 3.4.1 raf
    INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 0.3.7 mutationobserver-shim { uid: 1, name: 'readProjectConfiguration', branch: false, error: Error: File not found with singular glob: /var/www/html/Magnfi-master/node_modules/mutationobserver-shim mutationobserver.js at Glob.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Magnfi-master/node_modules/glob-stream/index.js:41:11) .......
```

Screenshot of error message

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @LarsFlieger I have added the error please check now